# How can I programmatically determine the default ringtone on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ringtone

Is there a way to determine which ringtone has been set as the default one on the user's iPhone from within my application?

If so, how can this be done?

> /Users/nikhil.dhamsania/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Media/iTunes_Control/iTunes/ringtones.plist

This is the path where the ringtones.plist file exist in the simulator can we do something like getting the status for active ringtone in the iPhone?

Comment: @7KV7: @Aravindhanarvi: check my updated question  it may be possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to say that but Apple is damn conservative.You cannot use or change the ringtones available programmatically.

Comment: i just wanted to know which ringtone is set for incoming call

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible in iphone... you are not allowed to  access that..