# Ring phone through coding in ios 7

Tags: ios

I needed to ring the phone with default ringtone in iOS 7 on some action from my application. Searched a lot on this but didn't got any topic related to this. So is it atleast possible in iOS or not? if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use or change the ringtones available programmatically. There is no public library. Also, there is no known workaround with private libraries.

See [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949692/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-the-default-ringtone-on-an-iphone) and [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455643/how-to-get-the-system-ringtones-programmingly-in-ios)